# React useCallback reference issue and closures . usecallback recreating on renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increase = useCallback(() => {
    let count = null;
    function incrementByOne() {
      count = count + 1;
      console.log(count);
    }
    return incrementByOne;
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
      <button onClick={increase()}>Increase</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

From the above code, when I click on the Increase button(second), the count increases by one and consoles it and it won't render but when I click on the first button, the state value changes and the component renders. Then when I click on the second button, the count starts from 1 previous count is initializing to zero after re renders even after using useCallback the increase method recreation on re render can anyone explain why the value is not persisting after the renders and useCallback recreating again?

Comment: When your component re-renders due to the state change, you are calling `increase()` again, creating a new `incrementByOne` closure over a new `count`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not `useCallback` returning a different function. When your component re-renders due to the state change, you are calling `increase()` again, creating a new `incrementByOne` closure over a new `count`. You can see this by adding `console.trace('re-initialising count')` in `increase`, right above `let count = null;`.

To fix this, you need to make sure to create the closure only once when the component is mounted, not on every render. One could use `useMemo()`, but the more reliable solution is to use the initialiser feature of `useState`, just with never updating the state:

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const [increment, _] = useState(() => {
    let count = 0;
    return () => {
      count = count + 1;
      console.log(count);
    };
  });

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
      <button onClick={increment}>Increase</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

However, the idiomatic React approach<sup>1</sup> would avoid the closure and mutable variable altogether, and rather use a ref:

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const countRef = useRef(0);
  const increment = () => {
    countRef.current = countRef.current + 1;
    console.log(countRef.current);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
      <button onClick={increment}>Increase</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

<sub>1: Or really, you should never mutate anything without re-rendering, so you could just use a normal state…</sub>